# How to declare folder name as global?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, python-2.7, python-addin

I have asked similar question at stackoverflow but posting here as well since it involves ArcGIS and python Add-In. Following code shows first step where i have to declare output folder as global so that later outputs can be saved in it as well. Right now I am getting an error at output folder string r'optfile/ras1'. Any help how to correctly store files in output folder and declare it as global would be appreciative.

```py
import arcpy
import os
import pythonaddins

from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
month = now.month
year = now.year

optfile = "C:/temp/"+str(year)+"_"+str(month)

class DrawRectangle(object):
"""Implementation for rectangle_addin.tool (Tool)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.cursor = 1
        self.shape = 'Rectangle'
        os.makedirs(optfile)        

def onRectangle(self, rectangle_geometry):
    """Occurs when the rectangle is drawn and the mouse button is released.
    The rectangle is a extent object."""

    extent = rectangle_geometry
    arcpy.Clip_management(r'D:/test', 
                          "%f %f %f %f" % (extent.XMin, extent.YMin, extent.XMax, extent.YMax), 
                          r'optfile/ras1', "#", "#", "NONE")
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Comment: The cross-posting for this has been answered on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536176/how-to-declare-folder-name-as-global so this question should be closed.

Comment: Not exactly. Use of global variables within python Add-In is still not working. I created a new function within Add-In class to declare string and required variables as global but no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the line where you call `arcpy.Clip_management` you reference r'optfile/ras1' which is a string, you want it to be:

```
os.path.join(optfile,ras1)
```

so that you can make use of the variable.

Comment: It gave an error saying "ras1 is not defined". It worked with:
optfile + '/ras1'

Comment: @Ibe, you need to learn the difference between [variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_%28computer_science%29) and [string literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal). It is a very important distinction in programming.

Comment: BTW, `os.path.join(optfile,"ras1")` should work presuming you want the output raster to always be named `ras1`.